# SOLID - Como aplicar el principio de responsabilidad unica (SRP)

Tags: c#

La clase "DistanciaPorDia" almacena y lee registros en un archivo Json.

Los datos que almacena son la fecha y una distancia recorida.

Quisiera saber como puedo aplicar el principio de responsabilidad unica, alguien me comento que podria crear una clase llamada "DistanciaPorDiaManager" para operaciones CRUD.

Tiene alguna idea de como podria hacer esta refactorizacion?

```
public class DistanciaPorDia
{
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public int MetrosRecoridos { get; set; }
        private string _rutaDeArchivo = @"c:\Datos\Json.txt";

        //Lee una lista de DistanciaPorDia desde un archivo Json 
        public List<DistanciaPorDia> LeerTodos()
        {
            //Si el archivo no existe regresa una lista vacia
            if (!File.Exists(_rutaDeArchivo)) return new List<DistanciaPorDia>();

            string datosJson;

            //Lee archivo en formato Json y lo almacena en datosJson
            using (StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader(_rutaDeArchivo))
            {
                datosJson = readtext.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //deserializa el archivo Json y regresa una lista de DistanciaPorDia
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DistanciaPorDia>>(datosJson);            
        }

        //Guarda una instacia de DistanciaPorDia en un archivo Json
        public void Guardar()
        {
            List<DistanciaPorDia> lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado = new List<DistanciaPorDia>();

            //Si existen datos previamente guardados los carga en lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado
            if (File.Exists(_rutaDeArchivo))
                lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado = LeerTodos();

            //Agrega la instacia actual a la lista de datos ya existentes
            lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado.Add(this);

            //Serializa la lista lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado);

            //Guarda la lista
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(_rutaDeArchivo))
            {
                w.WriteLine(output);
            }
        }      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el principio de responsabilidad única, básicamente se nos indica que un objeto debe dedicarse a realizar una única cosa.

Para tu caso tienes la clase DistanciaPorDia la cual se esta encargando de almacenar los datos en los atributos Fecha y MetrosRecoridos.

Pero ademas tienes dos métodos que se encargan de acceder a ficheros, los cuales podrían estar en otra clase que se dedique al manejo de archivos y no en la propia clase DistanciaPorDia.

Basado en tu pregunta, dejaría dos clases de la siguiente forma:

```
public class DistanciaPorDia
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public int MetrosRecoridos { get; set; }
}

public class JsonFileManager 
{
    private string _rutaDeArchivo = @"c:\Datos\Json.txt";

    //Lee una lista de DistanciaPorDia desde un archivo Json 
    public List<DistanciaPorDia> LeerTodos()
    {                
        //Lee archivo en formato Json y lo almacena en datosJson
        using (StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader(_rutaDeArchivo))
        {
            datosJson = readtext.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //deserializa el archivo Json y regresa una lista de DistanciaPorDia
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DistanciaPorDia>>(datosJson);            
    }

    //Guarda una instacia de DistanciaPorDia en un archivo Json
    public void Guardar(DistanciaPorDia data)
   {
        List<DistanciaPorDia> lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado = new List<DistanciaPorDia>();

        //Si existen datos previamente guardados los carga en lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado
        if (File.Exists(_rutaDeArchivo))
            lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado = LeerTodos();

        //Agrega la instacia actual a la lista de datos ya existentes
        lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado.Add(data);

        //Serializa la lista lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstDistanciaPorDiaGuardado);

        //Guarda la lista
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(_rutaDeArchivo))
        {
            w.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }      
}
```

Puedes leer el siguiente [articulo](https://devexperto.com/principio-responsabilidad-unica/), en el cual se indica como podemos detectar si no se esta respetando el SRP.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], un ejemplo en código ayudaría mucho, pues al momento solo es un enlace y una opinión amigo

Comment: Gracias BetaM, si leí el Cómo responder.  :)  En el enlace que le compartí estaban ejemplos con código. Lo que no tenia claro es  si podía copiarlos e indicar que pertenecían al enlace. Voy a intentar complementar de mejor manera la respuesta.

Comment: Claro que si puedes copiar aqui el contenido, dejando el enlace y los créditos a su respectivo autor. Saludos